# How to retrieve data from an array [Mongodb]

Tags: arrays, json, mongodb

I am trying to extract data from an array in a collection, the extract of code is shown below:

```
> db.nodes.findOne()
{
        "_id" : NumberLong(24060429),
        "_t" : "OsmNode",
        "uname" : "studerap",
        "uid" : 7260,
        "version" : 2,
        "changeset" : 634057,
        "timestamp" : ISODate("2007-11-27T11:18:58Z"),
        "tags" : [
                [
                        "created_by",
                        "almien_coastlines"
                ],
                [
                        "source",
                        "PGS"
                ]
        ],
        "tagKeys" : [
                "created_by",
                "source"
        ],
        "location" : [
                5.5442938804626465,
                -6.488432884216309
        ]
}
```

The data i actually want to retrieve is **5.5442938804626465** from the **location** array. Shall it be retrieved through index?

Thanks for helping

Comment: I tried: db.nodes.find({data.location[0]}) or db.nodes.find(data.location[0]) but those syntax are not correct

Comment: `db.nodes.findOne().location[0]` there's no `data`

Comment: Yes it worked am able to retrieve the 1st index.
But now, when i tried the db.nodes.find().location[0] for all data at location index 0, it does not works

Answer (score 0):

To extract that indexed element of array from all documents, you can get through:

```
var index = 0, count = 1;
var cursor = db.nodes.find({}, {_id:1, location:{$slice:[index, count]}});
```

Of course, you can write directly:

```
var cursor = db.nodes.find({}, {_id:1, location:{$slice:[0, 1]}});
```

Or

```
var cursor = db.nodes.find({}, {_id:1, location:{$slice:1}});
```

Then, extract the result:

```
var results = [];
cursor.forEach(function(e) {
    results.push(e.location[0]);
});
```

By the way, `.find()` returns a cursor; and `.findOne()` returns a document, which is equivalent to running `.find().next()` once if cursor has documents.